# Footnote text in footline of beamer poster

Tags: footnotes, beamerposter

I'm creating a poster template using this template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/yet-another-beamerposter-theme-with-variable-sizes-and-colour-themes-portrait-version/jgzfyrgpmvgk. I have modified the body of the text to only include three "wide column" blocks (i.e. no side-by-side columns). I would like to use footnotes in the body of the poster, but have the footnote text appear in the footline of the document, where the author and institution are (which I don't need and would like to remove). Currently, the footnote text appears between the end of my last wide column block and the top of the footline. I've tried modifying `\setbeamertemplate{footline}` to replace `\insertauthor` with `\footnotetext`, but it's not working. Help is appreciated!

Edit with MWE:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=a4,orientation=portrait,scale=2.5]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\usetheme{LLT-Poster}
\usecolortheme{ComingClean}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\large}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{inconsolata}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\author[\footnotemark I want footnotes in this box]{}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]\centering
        \begin{block}{textblock}
            blah blah\footnote[2]{I do not want footnotes here}.
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

beamercolorthemeComingClean.sty

```
% http://www.colourlovers.com/palette/352741/coming_clean
\definecolor{WinterSkin}{HTML}{EFE4CA}
\definecolor{AlwaysBeBabyToMe}{HTML}{F9F8E7}
\definecolor{Drift}{HTML}{E1E8D9}
\definecolor{Again}{HTML}{C0D9CF}
\definecolor{IAmMagazineSpine}{HTML}{2B2825}
\definecolor{HazySummerEve}{HTML}{3D7079}
\definecolor{ConspiciousCreep}{HTML}{D6156C}
\definecolor{Smak}{HTML}{790800}
\definecolor{TeBeso}{HTML}{FE6C6C}
\definecolor{Zen}{HTML}{DA6D5E}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=Smak}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=HazySummerEve}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=black,bg=WinterSkin}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=Zen, bg=AlwaysBeBabyToMe}
\setbeamercolor{palette quarternary}{fg=Zen, bg=AlwaysBeBabyToMe}
\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=Drift,bg=HazySummerEve}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=Drift}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=Drift,bg=HazySummerEve}
\setbeamercolor{foot}{bg=HazySummerEve,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in footline}{fg=Drift}
\setbeamercolor{institute in footline}{fg=Again}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=Again,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=AlwaysBeBabyToMe,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=HazySummerEve,bg=WinterSkin}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=Zen}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=Zen}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=Zen}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=Zen}
```

beamerthemeLLT-poster.sty

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\footimage}[1]{\def\footim@ge{#1}}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{headline}
     \vskip2em\centering
     \parbox{\linewidth}{\normalbaselines\centering\usebeamercolor{title in headline}\color{fg}{\bfseries\rmfamily\huge\inserttitle\par}}%
     \vskip2em
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{1em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamerfont{structure}{series=\bf,family=\sffamily,size=\Large}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\vspace*{-1ex}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body end}{\vspace*{-0.5ex}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\blacktriangleright\,$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\bullet$ }
\setlength\leftmargini{3.5em}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \vskip.75ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,sep=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
  }
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip1ex
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\small,family=\rmfamily}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{.5em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{footline}
     \vskip1.5ex
     \hspace{1em}\usebeamercolor{author in footline}{\bfseries\large\insertauthor}\par\vskip1ex
     \hspace{1em}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries\insertshortauthor}\par\vskip.8ex
     \hspace{1em}\usebeamercolor{institute in footline}{\color{fg}\small\bfseries\insertinstitute}\vskip1ex
   \end{beamercolorbox}
%
\ifdefined\footim@ge
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
  \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south east) %
  {\footim@ge};
\fi
}
```

Comment: It is customary to include a minimal working example (MWE) with questions.  Since I know your example, I edited your OP to include a MWE based on your project.